# Python Multiprocessing Pipe hang

Tags: python-3.x, pipe, multiprocessing

i'm trying to build a program to send a string to process Tangki and Tangki2 then send a bit of array data each to process Outdata, but it seems not working correctly. but when i disable gate to the Outdata everything works flawlessly.

this is the example code:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from time import sleep
import cv2


def outdata(input1,input2):
    while(1):
        room=input1.recv()
        room2=input2.recv()


def tangki(keran1,selang1):                             ##============tangki1
    a=None
    x,y,degree,tinggi=0,0,0,0
    dout=[]
    while(1):
        frame=keran1.recv()
        dout.append([x,y,degree,tinggi])
        selang1.send(dout)
        print ("received from: {}".format(frame))


def tangki2(keran3,selang2):                        ##=================tangki2
    x,y,degree,tinggi=0,0,0,0
    dout2=[]
    while(1):
        frame=keran3.recv()
        dout2.append([x,y,degree,tinggi])
        selang2.send(dout2) 
        print("received from: {}".format(frame))

def pompa(gate1,gate2):

    count=0
    while(1):
        count+=1
        gate1.send("gate 1, val{}".format(count))
        gate2.send("gate 2, val{}".format(count))




if __name__ == '__main__':

    pipa1, pipa2 = Pipe()
    pipa3, pipa4 = Pipe()
    tx1,rx1  = Pipe()
    tx2,rx2  = Pipe()

    ptangki = Process(target=tangki, args=(pipa2, tx1))
    ptangki2 = Process (target=tangki2, args=(pipa4, tx2))
    ppompa = Process(target=pompa, args=(pipa1,pipa3))
    keran = Process(target=outdata, args=(rx1,rx2))

    ptangki.start()
    ptangki2.start()
    ppompa.start()
    keran.start()

    ptangki.join()
    ptangki2.join()
    ppompa.join()
    keran.join()
```

at exact count reach 108 the process hang, not responding whatsoever. when i TOP it, the python3 process has gone, it seems that selang1 and selang2 causing the problem. i've search in google and it might be a Pipe Deadlock. so the question is how to prevent this from happening since i've already dump all data in pipe via repeated reading both in input1 and input2.

**Edit:** it seems that the only problem was the communication between tangki and tangki2 to outdata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's actually because buffer size limit? but adding `dout=[x,y,degree,tinggi]` and `dout=[x,y,degree,tinggi]` reset the size of data to minimal, or by assigning `dout=[0,0,0,0]` and `dout2=[0,0,0,0]` right after `selang1.send(dout)` and `selang2.send(dout2)`